# CSS relative positioned text

Tags: css, compass-sass

I have a navigation bar with dropdowns on hovering. Just at the bottom of it, I have a relative positioned text. When hovering triggers on the navbar, the dropdown menu comes down, but instead of hiding the relative text, the text still shows above the dropdown.

I know I could trigger a `hide()` with jquery when hovering, but is there a pure CSS approach?

Comment: have you tried playing with the z-index of the dropdown?

Comment: Can you paste some code or create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioned elements' (`relative`, `absolute`, and `fixed`) stacking order is set with `z-index`.

Set `z-index: 10` for the nav bar, and `z-index: 5` for the text.

Of course these numbers (5,10) are arbitrary, the important thing being that 5 < 10